# Adding a unique value filter to an strides moving windows in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

I already found two solutions for the strides moving windows which can compute mean, max, min, variance, etc. Now, I look to add a **count of unique value function** by axis. By axis, I mean compute all 2D arrays in single pass.

len(numpy.unique(array)) can make it but a lot of iterations will be needed to compute all arrays. I may work with image as big as 2000 x 2000, so iterations are not a good option. It's all about performance and memory effectiveness.

Here is the two solutions for the strides moving windows:

**First** is directly taken from Erik Rigtorp's at http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg29450.html

```
import numpy as np

def rolling_window_lastaxis(a, window):
    if window < 1:
       raise ValueError, "`window` must be at least 1."
    if window > a.shape[-1]:
       raise ValueError, "`window` is too long."
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

def rolling_window(a, window):
    if not hasattr(window, '__iter__'):
        return rolling_window_lastaxis(a, window)
    for i, win in enumerate(window):
        if win > 1:
            a = a.swapaxes(i, -1)
            a = rolling_window_lastaxis(a, win)
            a = a.swapaxes(-2, i)
    return a

filtsize = (3, 3)
a = np.zeros((10,10), dtype=np.float)
a[5:7,5] = 1

b = rolling_window(a, filtsize)
blurred = b.mean(axis=-1).mean(axis=-1)
```

**Second** is from Alex Rogozhnikov at http://gozhnikov.github.io/2015/09/30/NumpyTipsAndTricks2.html.

```
def compute_window_mean_and_var_strided(image, window_w, window_h):
   w, h = image.shape
   strided_image = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(image, 
                                                shape=[w - window_w + 1, h - window_h + 1, window_w, window_h],
                                                strides=image.strides + image.strides)
   # important: trying to reshape image will create complete 4-dimensional compy
   means = strided_image.mean(axis=(2,3)) 
   mean_squares = (strided_image ** 2).mean(axis=(2, 3)) 
   maximums = strided_image.max(axis=(2,3))

   variations = mean_squares - means ** 2
   return means, maximums, variations

image = np.random.random([500, 500])
compute_window_mean_and_var_strided(image, 20, 20)
```

Is there a way to add/implement a count of unique value function in one or both solutions?

**Clarification**: Basically, I need a Unique Value filter for a 2D array, just like numpy.ndarray.mean.

Thanks you

Alex

Comment: So, you are trying to compute `count of unique value function` in sliding windows along an axis?

Comment: How do your moving window dimensions and offsets compare? The smaller the offsets the higher the potential savings, obviously. Actually, the way in which means etc. are implemented in those snippets look far from optimal to me.

Comment: @Divakar I'm trying to add a count of unique value just like, means = strided_image.mean(axis=(2,3)) or maximums = strided_image.max(axis=(2,3)) of Alex Rogozhnikov exemple but more like unique = strided_image.unique(axis=(2,3)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach with [`scikit-image`'s `view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) for efficient sliding window extraction.

Steps involved :

- Get sliding windows.
- Reshape into 2D array. Note that this would make a copy and thus we would lose the efficiency of `views`, but keep it vectorized.
- Sort along the axis of merged block axes.
- Get the differentiation along that axes and count the number of different elements, which when added with `1` would be the count of unique values in each of those sliding windows and hence the final expected result.

The implementation would be like so -

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows as viewW

def sliding_uniq_count(a, BSZ):
    out_shp = np.asarray(a.shape) - BSZ + 1
    a_slid4D = viewW(a,BSZ)    
    a_slid2D = np.sort(a_slid4D.reshape(-1,np.prod(BSZ)),axis=1)    
    return ((a_slid2D[:,1:] != a_slid2D[:,:-1]).sum(1)+1).reshape(out_shp)
```

Sample run -

```
In [233]: a = np.random.randint(0,10,(6,7))

In [234]: a
Out[234]: 
array([[6, 0, 5, 7, 0, 8, 5],
       [3, 0, 7, 1, 5, 4, 8],
       [5, 0, 5, 1, 7, 2, 3],
       [5, 1, 3, 3, 7, 4, 9],
       [9, 0, 7, 4, 9, 1, 1],
       [7, 0, 4, 1, 6, 3, 4]])

In [235]: sliding_uniq_count(a, [3,3])
Out[235]: 
array([[5, 4, 4, 7, 7],
       [5, 5, 4, 6, 7],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [7, 5, 6, 6, 6]])
```

**Hybrid approach**

To make it work with very large arrays, to accommodate everything into memory, we might have to keep one loop that would iterate along each row of the input data, like so -

```
def sliding_uniq_count_oneloop(a, BSZ):
    S = np.prod(BSZ)
    out_shp = np.asarray(a.shape) - BSZ + 1
    a_slid4D = viewW(a,BSZ)    
    out = np.empty(out_shp,dtype=int)
    for i in range(a_slid4D.shape[0]):
        a_slid2D_i = np.sort(a_slid4D[i].reshape(-1,S),-1)
        out[i] = (a_slid2D_i[:,1:] != a_slid2D_i[:,:-1]).sum(-1)+1
    return out
```

**Hybrid approach - Version II**

Another version of hybrid one, with the explicit usage of `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` -

```
def sliding_uniq_count_oneloop(a, BSZ):
    S = np.prod(BSZ)
    out_shp = np.asarray(a.shape) - BSZ + 1   
    strd = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    m,n = a.strides
    N = out_shp[1]
    out = np.empty(out_shp,dtype=int)
    for i in range(out_shp[0]):
        a_slid3D = strd(a[i], shape=((N,) + tuple(BSZ)), strides=(n,m,n))
        a_slid2D_i = np.sort(a_slid3D.reshape(-1,S),-1)
        out[i] = (a_slid2D_i[:,1:] != a_slid2D_i[:,:-1]).sum(-1)+1
    return out
```

Comment: Work Good on small array, but I encounter MemoryError when I pass the real data. A raster 1300x3300 with resolution of 30 meters which is a landcover of ~40km x 100km. :-(

Comment: @AlexandreCharland Check out the newly added hybrid one.

Comment: Work good to remove  MemoryError, but If you try :
>>> x,y = 800, 2000
>>> image = np.random.randint(0,6,(x,y))
>>> result = sliding_uniq_count_oneloop(image, [20,20])
We got "ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size."

Comment: Read the docs of `viewW` to get a better feel for the limitations of this sliding window approach.

Comment: @AlexandreCharland Check out **Hybrid approach - Version II** .

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, it look like that. File "...\skimage\util\shape.py", line 263, in view_as_windows ==> arr_out = as_strided(arr_in, shape=new_shape, strides=strides)

Comment: @Divakar The Hybrid approach - Version II work good!!! Work on a 1000x2500 with a windows of 25x25. Took a couple of seconds. Hope that numpy will add an unique function on a 3D array like mean, max, etc. Great Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`np.mean` operates on a given axis without making any copies.  Looking at just the shape of the `as_strided` array it looks much bigger than the original array.  But because each 'window' is a view, it doesn't take up any additional space.  Reduction operators like `mean` work fine with that kind of view.

But note that your second example warns about `reshape`.  That creates a copy; it replicates the values in all of those windows.

`unique` starts with

```
ar = np.asanyarray(ar).flatten()
```

so right off the bat is is making a reshapened copy.  It's a copy, and 1d.  Then it sorts elements, looks for duplicates etc.

There are ways of finding `unique` rows, but they require converting rows into large structured array elements.  In effect turning a 2d array into a 1d that `unique` can work with.